# Force Visual Studio to add method calls in the designer like it does with SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I have created a `UserControl` with no controls on it. I do it all via paint operations. Therefore the control has a lot of properties and custom layout methods to calculate the positions and sizes of these drawn "controls". The layout methods are called when a property that affects the layout is changed.

This leads to an excessive call of my layout methods when a form with my `UserControl` is initialized. In my `UserControl` I prevented all unneccessary calls of the layout methods by using flags. But I have no control over the designer of a form where my `UserControl` is added.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to add a custom method before and after setting all properties in the designer like it does with `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout`? Or is there a completely different approach on designing such `UserControls`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're saying, what you should be doing is implementing the `ISupportInitialize` interface and putting your code in the `BeginInit` and `EndInit` methods. Try adding a `DataGridView` to a form and then check out the designer code to see that calls to those methods are added automatically to the `InitializeComponent` method.

Note that, in the designer code, the control is cast as the interface type to make that call. That's because convention is to make the implementation explicit, which means declaring the methods `Private` in VB, e.g.

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class InitialisedControl
    Implements ISupportInitialize

    Private Sub BeginInit() Implements ISupportInitialize.BeginInit
        '...
    End Sub

    Private Sub EndInit() Implements ISupportInitialize.EndInit
        '...
    End Sub

End Class
```

In that case, you can't access the members without casting as the interface type. Here's what my designer code file looks like with an instance of that control added:

```vb
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.InitialisedControl1 = New WindowsApp1.InitialisedControl()
        CType(Me.InitialisedControl1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'InitialisedControl1
        '
        Me.InitialisedControl1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
        Me.InitialisedControl1.Name = "InitialisedControl1"
        Me.InitialisedControl1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(150, 150)
        Me.InitialisedControl1.TabIndex = 2
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 450)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.InitialisedControl1)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        CType(Me.InitialisedControl1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub
    Friend WithEvents InitialisedControl1 As InitialisedControl
End Class
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I think I will make both methods public to be able to change multiple properties at any time without constant updates / layouts / repaints. Thank you.